# How to diagnose out of memory errors with TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tpu

I'm trying to train a variation of a u-net on a TPU and there appear to be 3 ops that are using 24 gigs of memory. Given that the network is quite large, I have no way of knowing where they are. How do you figure out the actual operations that these opaque stack traces refer to?

```
RuntimeError: Compilation failed: Compilation failure: Ran out of memory in memory space hbm. Used 27.90G of 16.00G hbm. Exceeded hbm capacity by 11.90G.

Total hbm usage >= 27.90G:
    reserved        528.00M
    program          27.38G
    arguments       unknown size

Output size unknown.

Program hbm requirement 27.38G:
    reserved          12.0K
    scoped             1.0K
    HLO temp         27.38G (5.6% utilization, 0.0% fragmentation (1.14M))

  Largest program allocations in hbm:

  1. Size: 8.00G
     Operator: op_type="CrossReplicaSum" op_name="tpu_139655909282424/CrossReplicaSum"
     Shape: f32[256,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0}
     Unpadded size: 128.00M
     Extra memory due to padding: 7.88G (64.0x expansion)
     XLA label: %cross-replica-sum = f32[256,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0} cross-replica-sum(f32[256,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0} %bitcast.1), replica_groups={{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}}, barrier="custom:0", to_apply=%sum.902, metadata={op_type="CrossReplicaSum" op_name="tpu_139655909282424/CrossRep...
     Allocation type: HLO temp
     ==========================

  2. Size: 8.00G
     Operator: op_type="Mul" op_name="tpu_139655909282424/mul_1"
     Shape: f32[8,32,512,128,2]{4,3,2,1,0}
     Unpadded size: 128.00M
     Extra memory due to padding: 7.88G (64.0x expansion)
     XLA label: %fusion.4 = (f32[8,32,512,128,2]{4,3,2,1,0}, f32[8,32,512,128,2]{4,3,2,1,0}) fusion(f32[8]{0} %fusion.1265, f32[32,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0} %reshape.319, f32[32,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0} %copy.5), kind=kLoop, calls=%fused_computation.4, metadata={op_type="Mul" op_nam...
     Allocation type: HLO temp
     ==========================

  3. Size: 8.00G
     Operator: op_type="Mul" op_name="tpu_139655909282424/mul_1"
     Shape: f32[8,32,512,128,2]{4,3,2,1,0}
     Unpadded size: 128.00M
     Extra memory due to padding: 7.88G (64.0x expansion)
     XLA label: %fusion.4 = (f32[8,32,512,128,2]{4,3,2,1,0}, f32[8,32,512,128,2]{4,3,2,1,0}) fusion(f32[8]{0} %fusion.1265, f32[32,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0} %reshape.319, f32[32,512,128,2]{3,2,1,0} %copy.5), kind=kLoop, calls=%fused_computation.4, metadata={op_type="Mul" op_nam...
     Allocation type: HLO temp
     ==========================
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the traceback of the definition point of an operation through the [`traceback`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#traceback) / [`traceback_with_start_lines`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#traceback_with_start_lines) properties. For example, to print the traceback for an op you could write a function like:

```py
def print_op_traceback(op):  # Note it takes a tf.Operation, for a tf.Tensor use tensor.op
    for f, lno, func, line in op.traceback:
        print(f'{f}:{lno} ({func})\n    {line}')
        # Or before Python 3.6
        # print('{}:{} ({})\n    {}'.format(f, lno, func, line))
```

Then you can see the traceback for the problematic operations with [`get_operation_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name):

```py
op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('tpu_139655909282424/CrossReplicaSum')
print_op_traceback(op)
```

Comment: But this is happening when the model is being compiled (I'm using tf.keras). How am I suppose to save the graph so that I can reload it after the error occurs?

Comment: @Luke Ah I see, I thought the problem was when running or training the model. I'm not sure why the graph compilation only should take so much memory. I'm seeing it that most of the memory is under `Extra memory due to padding`, it's making things 64 times bigger than the "unpadded size", is that normal? In any case, you don't need to save the graph to run the code above, just run it in some alive graph containing those ops. Not sure if it could work, but maybe you can capture that exception and try to get the traceback of those ops on the `except` block?